# angularjs bootstrap popover data-binding not working

Tags: angularjs

Currently, i am trying to make the angularjs popover data binding work.

Here is the html part:

```
<div id="sortable" ng-repeat="object in arrayForShow">
   <div ng-class="classGenerate(object)" class="well nomargin" id="resizable" pop-over-width-offset argument='object'>
       {{object.default}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Now: ng-repeat item: **object** is passed into directive **pop-over-width-offset**.

In the popOverWidthOffset directive:  **I am trying the make the template html be able to access the **argument** (which I set in the scope in the directive).**

```
app.directive "popOverWidthOffset", ($templateCache)->
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'CustomiseFormCtrl'
    scope: {
        argument: '='
    }
    link: (scope, element, attrs)->
        popOverContent = $templateCache.get('angular/templates/popOverCustomisationChangeWidthOffset.html')
        options = {
            content: popOverContent,
            placement: "top",
            html: true,
        }
        $(element).popover(options)
```

popOverCustomisationChangeWidthOffset.html:

```
<form>
    {{argument}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile) the content of the pop-over:

```
compiledPopOverContent = $compile(popOverContent)(scope);
```